# facebook graph API - comments limited to 999

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch all comments for a particular Facebook post via the FB Graph API.

The call for the post itself:

`graph.facebook.com/129047777209815_279367092177882/?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

yields that there are 5278 comments.

Querying for the comments with offset=900, limit=100:

`https://graph.facebook.com/129047777209815_279367092177882/comments?limit=100&offset=900&value=1&base_amount=1&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&__after_id=129047777209815_279367092177882_1122143`

yields

`"paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/129047777209815_279367092177882/comments?limit=100&offset=1000&value=1&base_amount=1&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&__after_id=129047777209815_279367092177882_1122270"}`

Yet querying

`graph.facebook.com/129047777209815_279367092177882/comments?limit=100&offset=1000&value=1&base_amount=1&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&__after_id=129047777209815_279367092177882_1122270`

doesn't give me any comments at all.
It's not just this post, I've noticed consistently that I can never retrieve more than 999 comments.
Can anyone tell me how to get more than 999 comments? Is this a Facebook limit? I can't find it in the docs.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using the `__after_id` token?
The following seems to work perfectly in the Graph API Explorer.

```
129047777209815_279367092177882/comments?limit=100&offset=5277&value=1&base_amount=1
```

The above retrieves the **5278th** comment. Try it out in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=129047777209815_279367092177882/comments?limit=100&offset=5277&value=1&base_amount=1).

The limit of 999 might apply to the `__after_id` parameter. It doesn't seem to be well-documented. [(Related Bug)](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/122972287842422?browse=search_501902014a7c80268618845)

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply. The problem appears to be access token related; when I use an access token generated by the Graph API Explorer everything works correctly. Before I was generating a client_credentials access token (using {"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id": <APP_ID>, "client_secret": <APP_SECRET_ID>}) and this was restricting me to 1000 comments? In any case pointing me to the explorer solved the issue, thanks.

Comment: The `offset` parameter is undocumented. Thank you @AnirudhRamanathan.