# Can't paginate past 1000 Facebook comments via API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I've got a Facebook post with at least 4,000 confirmed public comments. But I can't get more than 980 of them.

Every time, once I clear 900, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "fb_pcf_temp.py", line 41, in <module>
    next = decoded['paging']['next']
KeyError: 'next'
```

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
postgrabber.py

Created by ian on 2012-09-24.
Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
"""

import sys
import os
import ogp
import config
import httplib
import simplejson as json
import requests

getData = ogp.facebookQueries()
post_id = "145061248901557_381440708596942"

def getmore(nexturl):
    access_token = getData.authenticate()
    theFeedUrl = nexturl + "&" + access_token
    print theFeedUrl
    req = requests.get(theFeedUrl)
    f = req.text
    decoded = json.loads(f)
    return decoded

next = "https://graph.facebook.com/%s?fields=comments.limit(100).fields(likes,message,from,like_count)" % post_id
x = 0
while x < 40:
    decoded = getmore(next)
    try:
        comments = decoded['comments']['data']
        next = decoded['comments']['paging']['next']

    except:
        comments = decoded['data']
        next = decoded['paging']['next']

    for d in comments:
        print '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t"%s"' % (d['created_time'],d['like_count'],d['from']['name'],d['from']['id'],d['message'])
    x = x + 1
```

I'm positive I've got well more than 1000 public comments. The post has 4780 total comments - not likely that 3800 of them are marked private, I think.

Has anyone else encountered this? Am I doing something obvious wrong?

Comment: If it's similar to reddit, you can't grab past the first 1000 for performance / cache reasons.

Comment: Don't think so - Facebook has pagination set up just for this kind of thing, and you can even grab 1000 or more at a time, or batch the request.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [facebook graph API - comments limited to 999](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756935/facebook-graph-api-comments-limited-to-999): the answer there may help you.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that, but it didn't address the problem. It IS true that I can get past 1000 in the Explorer, though. Not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Amazing how asking a bunch of other people suddenly reveals the facepalm.

I had this:

```
    theFeedUrl = nexturl + "&" + access_token
```

It should have been:

```
    theFeedUrl = nexturl + "&access_token=" + access_token
```

Silly careless mistake, further compounded by the fact that, for some reason, Facebook let me request the first 1000 w/o the correct URL.